# Use new DataFrames.combine returned column as argument in Julia

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I am trying to use `DataFrames.combine` to chain multiple transformations. The desired final DataFrame is the one below.

```
using DataFrames, Statistics

df = DataFrame(x = repeat([1], 4))

df_2 = combine(df, 
        :x => sum => :sum_x)

df_2.sqrt_sum_x .= sqrt.(df_2.sum_x)

println(df_2)
#1×2 DataFrame
# Row │ sum_x  sqrt_sum_x 
#     │ Int64  Float64
#─────┼───────────────────
#   1 │     4         2.0
```

I was wondering if there is any way of achieving the previous result with a single call to `combine`. E.g. by using the new `target_cols` `:sum_x` as a column in the argument (see code below). However, this seems to throw an `ArgumentError` as it can not find the newly computed `:sum_x` column.

```
combine(df, 
        :x => sum => :sum_x,
        :sum_x => sqrt => :sqrt_sum_x)
# ERROR: ArgumentError: column name :sum_x not found in the data frame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not allowed. The reason is that the order of execution of transformations in `combine` is undefined. In particular, in some situations these operations are executed in parallel using multi-threading (to improve performance).

Additionally such operation could potentially be problematic in interpretation for example if you would have written:

```
combine(df, 
        :x => sum => :sum_x,
        [:x, :sum_x] => (+) => :x_plus_sum_x)
```

then in transformation:

```
[:x, :sum_x] => + => :x_plus_sum_x
```

`:x` would come from the source data frame `df` (and have 4 elements), while `:sum_x` would come from "yet not existent" target data frame (and have 1 element). Technically it would be possible to make it work, but we considered that this could be confusing.